# psycopg2 package installation problems

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

Tried to install psycopg in a virtual environment on Python 3.11, but I get the error "pg_config executable not found".

Was getting a C compiler related error before. The problem was solved by installing the build-essential package.
Now I get another error and don't know what to do. I am new to Linux.

EDIT:
OS: Ubuntu 22.04
Command used: pip install psycopg2
I use PostgreSQL running via dockerfile

Comment: To your question text add 1) OS and version. 2) The exact command you are using to install. 3) Do you have Postgres installed on this machine? If so how did you install it?

Comment: try `pip3 install psycopg`

Comment: It didn't work. Same error

Comment: 1) `pip3 install psycopg` would not change anything as there is only one version of Python in a virtual environment and `pip` == `pip3`. 2) `pg_config` is a Postgres program and the `psycopg2` install cannot find it in the Docker container. 3) Per [Install](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html) the easiest thing to do is run `pip install psycopg2-binary`. Be sure and read the *psycopg vs psycopg-binary* section. 4) Otherwise read *Build prerequisites* section from above link.